# retrive data from firebase in java iwant to read text "Antenna" and put it in text view

Tags: java, firebase

DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Students").child(user.getUid());

[image]

```
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
               String s1 = (String) snapshot.child("courses").child("1").child("name").getValue();
```

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code, errors and and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Lastly, images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question. Also `courses` appears to have an array as a child with numeric indexes; "1" is a String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your DatabaseReference isn't right, u have "Students" and your node is named "Student", change it and then try this. Where i wrote "yourTextView" place the view where you want to set the text.

```
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
           String s1 = snapshot.child("courses").child("1").child("name").getValue().toString();
           yourTextView.setText(s1);
```

Hope this works for you!